# How to dedicate i686-w64-mingw32-g++ version

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw

I need MinGW to build our older code. But the complier is too new cause function always fail.

My work environment:

Windows11-WSL2(Ubuntu 22 lts)

First, I check `i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -v`, And ubuntu sent back:

`-bash: /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-g++: No such file or directory`

So, I use `sudo apt install g++-mingw-w64-i686-posix` to install mingw-w64. Then key `i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -v` again. Now I can get version: `gcc version 10-posix 20220113 (GCC)`

But how can I install dedicated version to
`gcc version 4.9.3 20150626 (Fedora MinGW 4.9.3-1.el7) (GCC)`?

Comment: Do you really need an old compiler? Can't you just reduce the c++ standard version? Gcc is mostly backwards compatible

Comment: "MinGW" is an abbreviation of Minimal GNU for Windows. It's an environment usually installed in Windows, that allows one to use GCC in Windows. There are Linux packages and source, but those are for *cross-compilation* of Windows executable programs.

Comment: Also, both GCC and the MinGW environment are open-source. The sources are available, and can be built by yourself if you desperately need a specific version and can't use flags/options to build your projects.

Comment: @ Alan Birtles. Do you mean the toolchain which I need to rebuild by myself?

Comment: I use the chapter "Mixing Linux and Windows commands" to set i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe. It works to me. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/filesystems).